# Whether to close some connections after using different threads to connect to different databases will affect other threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to create some threads to connect different databases,Each thread creates a connection object, and the thread should have no shared connection object.

When I run the code, it will show the `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute cursor`,and Prompt to stop working

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self,func,args,name = ''):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.name = name
    self.func = func
    self.args = args

  def run(self):
    self.func(*self.args)

    #other code
    ...        

    #I have not used join() because they run in an infinite loop
    threads = []
    for i in range(21,53):
        t = MyThread(self.dojob,(i,strsql))
        threads.append(t)

    for t in threads:
        t.start()

    #This is what the thread does.
    coon = self.connectdb(id)     #Connect different databases with different ids
    c = coon.cursor()
    x = c.execute(strsql)
    data = x.fetchall()
    fm = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['no1', 'no2', 'no3'])    # Export
    fm.to_excel('H:\{0}{1}.xlsx'.format(id, d[id]), 
                index=False, encoding='utf-8')
    c.close()
    coon.close()
```